# pandas dataframe : get the index of a given row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like below:

```
d = pandas.DataFrame({1:{1,2,3}}, index={0:{103,104,105}})
```

I want to get the index of a given row. For example, the index of df.iloc[1] should be 104. How can I do that?

Comment: Use `df.index[1]`

Comment: You should use df.index

Comment: try `d.iloc[1].name` this will return `104`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `df.index[i]` where i is the number of the row you want starting from 0.

Answer (score 0):

You must read the [`pandas.dataframe.index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) documentation for the deep insight. Or [`pandas.DataFrame.index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/indexing.html) nice documentation itself.